# How to add a Discord modal to a button in Python using discord.py

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, modal-dialog

i would like to ask if its possible to add discord modal into button (after pressing button, modal will show up)

my button:

```
class Report(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=86400)
        self.value = None
     
    @discord.ui.button(label="Report", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def report(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    #and so on
```

expecting discord modal to showup after button interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can send your modal with [InteractionResponse.send_modal](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_modal) in your button callback.

```
class Report(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=86400)
        self.value = None
     
    @discord.ui.button(label="Report", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def report(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal() #
```

References: [discord.ui.Modal](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Modal)